# I create a code to madd dm everyone in a server through a self bot but i am getting this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

```
ypeError: _0x3f232e[_0x209805(...)][_0x209805(...)] is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ADVAITH\Desktop\dm\DMALL\index.js:1:5799)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\ADVAITH\Desktop\dm\DMALL\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\ADVAITH\Desktop\dm\DMALL\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\ADVAITH\Desktop\dm\DMALL\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\ADVAITH\Desktop\dm\DMALL\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\ADVAITH\Desktop\dm\DMALL\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\ADVAITH\Desktop\dm\DMALL\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:315:20)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11040) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11040) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`enter code here`
```

and this is my error i am getting and  tried many way t9o solve but i  am failingb  pls help me

Comment: Please be more specific on what you are trying to do here (the steps to reproduce).
It looks like an error that was thrown asynchronously.

Comment: 1) Self bots are against Discord Terms of Service
2) Mass Dming in servers is API Spam and can lead to bots getting banned

Comment: First of all, self-bots are no longer even supported by discord.js. Second, as Elitezen mentioned they are against the Discord ToS. Third, the primary implementations of what you are trying to do are malicious in nature (such as the creation of a spam bot). In short, it is best if you **do not do this in any way, shape, or form**.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments:

1. Self-bots are no longer even supported by discord.js. Errors are to be expected, and it is highly possible that what you want to do isn't even possible anymore.
2. As Elitezen mentioned, self-bots are against the Discord ToS. Doing something like **this will without a doubt get your bot and/or your own account banned** from Discord.
3. The primary implementations of what you are trying to do here are malicious in nature (such as the creation of a spam bot or a raid bot). Even if that is not what you are trying to do here, it is still most likely the case that what you are attempting to do is not possible; plus, there will be significant consequences for breaking the terms of service that you accepted when you first joined Discord.

In short, it is best if you do not attempt to do this in any way, shape, or form. Trust me, creating this mass-messaging self-bot is not worth the time and consequences.

Also note that we would not have been able to solve your problem regardless. You didn't provide any of your code, you only gave us a generic error that we cannot address since we don't have your code.